# Can an equation be reverse engineered?

Tags: calculus

Can an equation be reverse engineered. Like as the parametric equation of a line can be drawn through general equation of the line. can we reverse engineer the parametric equation to get the general equation of the line back. this is just an example. My question is for generic

Comment: Are you thinking about something like interpolation? The question is not clear.

Comment: it is not clear what you ask, but for the example of the line, yes it is possible.

Comment: Your question seems to be this: “given a parametric equation for a curve, can we wrote a non-parametric equation describing the curve?” Is that right?

Comment: If your question where as suggested by @kccu, then it would be a good question. However, you explicitly wrote "this is just an example. My question is for generic", which throws the question into the realm of "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Do you mean $\begin{cases}x=x_0+\alpha t,\\y=y_0+\beta t\end{cases}$ vs. $ax+by+c= 0$ ?

Comment: @kccu exactly. can we do that?!

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is "elimination".

When you have a parametric representation say for example of a line

$$\begin{cases}x&=&2t+1\\y&=&t-3\end{cases}$$

it suffices to extract $t$, say, from the second equation $t=y+3$ and plug it into the first one :

$$x=2(y+3)+1 \iff x-2y-7=0$$

(one says that we have eliminated in this way the 'time' parameter $t$ between the two equations, getting an implicit equation).

This is always possible, though less immediate when $x=P(t),y=Q(t)$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials with degrees $p,q$ higher than $1$, moreover not necessarily with $p=q$, thanks to the "resultant" theory  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

I will not expand this theory. I will only give an example.

Consider the curve with parametric equations :$$\begin{cases}x&=&t^3+t+1\\y&=&2t^2-t+3\end{cases}$$

We write these constraints under the form :

$$\begin{cases}f(t)&:=&t^3+t+(1-x)&=&0\\g(t)&:=&2t^2-t+(3-y)&=&0\end{cases}$$

and form the resultant $Res(f,g)$ which is a determinant using $q$ times the coefficients of $f$ and $p$ times those of $g$ (with shifts) that we equate to $0$ :

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&1&(1-x)&0\\0&1&0&1&(1-x)\\2&-1&(3-y)&0&0\\0&2&-1&(3-y)&0\\0&0&2&-1&(3-y)\end{vmatrix}=0$$

It remains to expand this determinant to obtain the following implicit equation of the curve :

$$ y^3 - 8x^2 + 6xy - 5y^2 + 3x  + 2y - 1=0$$

Remark : One can find resultants of different species ; this one is Sylvester's resultant, but there as well Cayley, Dixon's, etc. resultants https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/074d/652f97d07a2d5150764c2f448a6d98d3ab3b.pdf). Resultants, under different extensions are a cornerstone for solving systems of polynomial equations. see for e.g., papers of Dinesh Manocha, as this one :

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/73e7/755a491a1a796a307949e81c37680276a993.pdf

Comment: see as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704281